# MVC 5 Date Format is displaying as MM/dd/yyyy in Edit when I want dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I know this is an old problem that has been answered many times but I have searched for several months without solving my problem. 
My app is local only and needs to be en AU. I am a newbe and answers I have found relate to a global file which MVC 5 does not have so am thoroughly confused (I assume I use Startup.cs ??). Don't know whether I need a custom route or a custom model binder.

Model

```
{
    public partial class SuspensionHist
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        public int AssociId { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public short SuspensionNo { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime SuspensionDate { get; set; }
        public short? OffenceNo { get; set; }
        public bool? SuspensionServed { get; set; }
        public byte[] SsmaTimeStamp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

// GET: SuspensionHists/Edit/5
        public async Task Edit(int? AssociId, short? SuspensionNo, DateTime SuspensionDate)
        {
            if (AssociId == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

```
        if (SuspensionNo == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (SuspensionDate == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var suspensionHist = await _context.SuspensionHist.FindAsync(AssociId, SuspensionNo, SuspensionDate);
        if (suspensionHist == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.SuspensionNo = new SelectList(_context.Suspension, "SuspensionNo", "SuspensionNo");
        return View(suspensionHist);
    }

    // POST: SuspensionHists/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? AssociId, short? SuspensionNo, DateTime SuspensionDate, [Bind("AssociId,SuspensionNo,SuspensionDate,OffenceNo,SuspensionServed,SsmaTimeStamp")] SuspensionHist suspensionHist)
    {
        if (AssociId != suspensionHist.AssociId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (SuspensionNo != suspensionHist.SuspensionNo)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (SuspensionDate != suspensionHist.SuspensionDate)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(suspensionHist);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!SuspensionHistExists(suspensionHist.AssociId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(suspensionHist);
    }
```

Comment: How are you generating the input in the view? What is the culture on your server?

Comment: The server is set to Auto (but I have tried dd/MM/yyyy - no change). The Index view displays correctly:

Comment: It is a scaffolded controller. The Index view points at the Edit as below.
                      
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { AssociId = item.AssociId, SuspensionNo = item.SuspensionNo, SuspensionDate = item.SuspensionDate }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { AssociId = item.AssociId, SuspensionNo = item.SuspensionNo, SuspensionDate = item.SuspensionDate })
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

Comment: Edit View displays in US format.ie 15/06/2018 displays as 06/15/2018 00:00:00 and gives a not valid error on save.

Comment: Part of Edit View            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SuspensionDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SuspensionDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SuspensionDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

Comment: Create works (and displays the date correctly).Delete displays correctly but gives an error on submit.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity. Think it cant find the record.

Comment: Also refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416537/design-first-datetime-key-my-scaffolded-controller-is-finding-mm-dd-yyyy-instea  Different table same problem.

Comment: There is a whole lot of stuff here that is confusing. First you have `IActionResult` and are using TagHelpers` which means this is core-mvc, not mvc-5 as you have tagged it.

Comment: Then you have `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` which generates the browsers HTML-5 datepicker which will display the date in the browsers culture and post back in ISO format. But for that to work correctky then you must use `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" in your `[DisplayFormat]` attribute (refer [Specify Date format (dd/MM/yyyy)
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820926/specify-date-format-in-mvc5-dd-mm-yyyy/43826746#43826746)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stephen. Sorry about the tagging. Just didn't know any better. Am not trying to use data picker, just trying to display all dates in dd/MM/yyyy format.Tried DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" in Model. That changes the Index view date format from dd/MM/yyyy to yyyy-MM-dd but does not change the edit view at all. it still displays as MM/dd/yyyy 00:00:00. This is the bit that is confusing me. The closest reference I have found is https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1078167/DateTime-Issue-In-MV but I don't know how to apply it to my project (which is core-mvc as you say).

Comment: I have other tables within this app with dates and they display and update  ok. The difference seems to be that the date in this table (and a couple of others also giving me trouble) is part of the key. I believe this is a routing problem rather than a display problem but havent found an answer as yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Yas Ikeda for the following: The problem is to do with '/' in the urls. On the Index View I have changed the link from:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { AssociId = item.AssociId, SuspensionNo = item.SuspensionNo, CalendarDate = item.CalendarDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") })
```

to

```
 <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-Associid="@item.AssociId" asp-route-SuspensionNo="@item.SuspensionNo" asp-route-SuspensionDate="@item.SuspensionDate.ToString("o")">Edit</a>
```

This fixes the routing problem and the Edit now works ok.